# Detecting multiple key press at once and don't response when other keys are pressed

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have an admin panel, and I want to set a keyboard shortcut that redirects the user to this panel when he presses {A+D+M+N} all at the same time.

I have this code:

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // use e.keyCode
};
```

But it works only for one key press, it doesn't work for multiple key detection.

**Also, I wont to detect (A+D+M+N) only, and if user pressed all the buttons on the keyboard, or (A+D+M+N+X+Z) for example, it should not response.**

Any ideas or frameworks to implement that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. What have you [investigated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[keyPressListener](https://github.com/RyadPasha/keyPressListener), is a library that I've developed for that matter.

Firstly, since you want to match only your preferred keys without any other keys, then make sure to set `ignoreOtherInput` to `false`:

```
keyPressListener.config({ignoreOtherInput: false});
```

Secondly, now you can call the listener function:

```
keyPressListener.when('A+D+M+N', function(){
  window.location.href = '/admin-panel'; // If user pressed (A+D+M+N), go to admin panel
});
```

So if the user pressed (A+D+M+N) it will redirect him to the admin panel
and if he pressed all the buttons on the keyboard, or (Ctrl+A+D+M+N) for example, it won't response.

More: @https://github.com/RyadPasha/keyPressListener